# Prebuild trainer for video face recognition processing in opencv c++

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, video-processing, face-recognition

Currently i am trying on Gender recognition/ classifcation using OpenCV and Fisherface Algorithm. At the moment, i am training my program with apporximately 2500+ images due with different lightings.

Problem is it takes me 35 minutes to execute my file. Everytime i execute my file i have to re-train my program. Which will be processing 2500+ images and takes 35 minutes before video face recognition program comes on.

My xecution line in terminal

```
./main haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml image_to_train.txt 0
```

./main will be the object build from cpp/ .exe in Windows

haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml is for face detection provided by opencv

image_to_train.txt is where 2500 images are

0 is for webcam

Is there anyway to pre-built the .txt file on iamges so i dont have to retrain them everytime. I was thinking about a database, but then a database usually runs a single image processing through the whole database again(brute-force concept).

Codes of training the program are these two lines in the entire video recognition process. Images are passed into these functions one by one for 2500 images thus the execution time.Looking into OpenCV documentation i still didnt get any idea on how can i extract data out of them and process them to make execution a lot faster. A prebuild excuting trainer.

```
  Ptr<FaceRecognizer> model = createFisherFaceRecognizer();
    model->train(images, labels);
```

Comment: I wish I could help you. I would guess that maybe some sort of program or utility that can store a snapshot of your program in memory might be able to help you. Being able to load the exact state of a program and just resume execution would be helpful in this case without having to go through the entire feeding process.

Comment: yes, ofc. you can save() to xml/yml, and later load() that again, instead of re-training.

Comment: @Cinch in OpenCV only Local Binary Patterns Histograms(Lbph) algorithm has this function. To save and resume. Problem is when i interchange the function with fisherface, the webcam starts lagging. Webcam saves the picture and compares them to it's trained search. I am suspecting that when using Lbph the processing takes a much longer time causing some lost frames and thus the lag. That was tested with 800+ images. A 3 - 4 minute execution time.

Comment: @berak how can i do that?

Comment: why don't you read the [docs](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/contrib/doc/facerec/facerec_api.html) ? (why do i have to point you there, even ?)

Comment: LBPH I think is the way to go anyway. I'm doing prity much what @QWERTY is doing (face, gender, and age detection) but I only re-train if I add new images, otherwise i just use the saved .xml files which is the difference between 20min start up and 5 seconds start up.